# Trying to integrate a docker ipvlan network into my network using ubuntu as router

Tags: networking, docker

I have configured an ubuntu 20.04 as my home router (wired only so far), my network topology is as follows:

[image: Network Topology]

So far so good, my ubuntu is working fine as a router (I have NAT and ip forwarding), At the end I'm leaving all the configuration I have done to achieve it.

What I need now is to have some docker containers accessible from the network (not just through the host), for that I have created a Docker IPVlan network as follows:

###### Docker IPVlan

```
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet 172.20.0.0/24 --gateway 172.20.0.1 -o parent=lan ipvlanet
```

###### Busybox container to check internet access

```
docker run --name test --rm --network ipvlanet --ip 172.20.0.5 -ti busybox sh
/ # ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.0.101): 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ # ping 172.20.0.1
PING 172.20.0.1 (172.20.0.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 172.20.0.1 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

If I initiate a ping I can do it, however it seems I can't connect to a container via a port, this is key for all other services I will need to launch

###### From my computer [172.20.0.7] I can ping the container

```
> ping 172.20.0.5
PING 172.20.0.5 (172.20.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.436 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.787 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.746 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.756 ms
^C
--- 172.20.0.5 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.746/0.931/1.436/0.292 ms
```

Any ideas?

### More info!

###### /etc/netplan/01-onepot.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        eth1:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        eth2:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [192.168.100.2/24]
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 192.168.100.1
            nameservers:
                search: []
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
    bridges:
        lan:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            interfaces: [eth0, eth1]
            addresses: [172.20.0.1/24]
            nameservers:
                search: []
                addresses: [172.20.0.1]
```

###### /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=1.0.0.1
DNSStubListener=no
```

###### /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;

host naboo {
  hardware ethernet <my mac address>;
  fixed-address 172.20.0.7;
}

subnet 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 172.20.0.50 172.20.0.200;
}

option routers 172.20.0.1;
option domain-name-servers 172.20.0.1;
```

###### my pihole DNS service

```
docker run \
  --name pihole \
  --mount type=volume,source=pihole-etc,target=/etc \
  --network host \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  -e TZ="America/Santiago" \
  -e WEBPASSWORD='supersecurepassword' \
  -d $PIHOLE_IMG
```

Comment: Hi All, I started from scratch again and this time I'm not having any issues, I'm able to start for example an openssh server and connect to it over the network, I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time